# Mysql server on kubernetes wont restart

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, fedora

im trying to restart my mysql server. The server is on a Kubernetes/fedora container. I have tried to use # /etc/init.d/mysqld restart and # systemctl restart mysqld. The problem is that there is no files in the init.d.
When running # /etc/init.d/mysqld restart bash says No such file, obviously as there is no such file. When running # systemctl restart mysqld it responds "bash: systemctl: Command not found"
The mysql-servier is running fine and i can log into it, however i cant restart it. Please help.

Comment: command not found to what?

Comment: Sorry for that, when running # /etc/init.d/mysqld restart bash says No such file, obviously as there is no such file. When running # systemctl restart mysqld it responds "bash: systemctl: Command not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The mysql-servier is running fine and i can log into it, however i cant restart it.

You have 2 options and both have it's 'dangers' to address:

- More likely, container is started with either `CMD` given in docker image or `command` directive in kubernetes manifest that is actually starting your mysql. In that case, regardless of the way you manage to do termination (during restart) of running instance of mysql on that container you will also - terminate the whole container. Kubernetes will then restart that container, or whole pod.
- Less likely, but possible is that container was started with some other 'main' command, and mysql is started as part of a separate script. In that case inspecting docker file or kubernetes manifest will give you details about start/stop procedure and only in that case you can restart mysql without actually killing the container it is running onto.

Dangers: data persistence. If you don't have proper data persistence in place killing running container (either through restart or refresh) will also destroy any ephemeral data with it.

Additional note: have you tried `service mysql status` and `service mysql restart`?

Comment: Thank you! this helped! With better understanding i was able to make a better config for a new container. About service command, this is also "not found".

Answer (score 1):

To restart a server on Kubernetes you simply need to delete the pod with `kubectl delete pod <id>`. If you didn't create pod manually, but rather with a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), it will restart and come back online automatically.

Deleting a pod is a correct way of shutting down servers. First Kubernetes will send mysql a TERM signal that will politely ask it to shutdown. Then after some time (configurable) it will shoot it with KILL if it doesn't comply.

Comment: Thank you, however the thing was that i changed the config for mysql and wanted to restart just the server and not the entire pod. I hade to make a new container instead with a little different config. I am doing a lot of performance testing and just wanted an easy way to make mysql do what i wanted.

Comment: What you are describing (make a new container with a little different config) is the intended way of operation. You can hide docker build, kubectl delete pod behind a small shell script, and it will be as easy as restarting the server inside a container, but in a more true Docker way.